# Is there a function or a way of getting a remainder or modulus with equations with "surds"?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, number-theory

So I'm working with "surds", or radicals.  I have expressions like

$$7 + 5\sqrt{2} + 6\sqrt{3} + 7\sqrt{6}\tag{1}$$

and I want to take the "coefficients", for lack of a better word, and take their remainder when divided by $p$.

For example, if $p=4$, Equation (1) becomes:

$$3 + \sqrt{2} + 2\sqrt{3} + 3\sqrt{6}$$

...again, by taking each number in front and finding the remainder when dividing by $4$.

Also, could someone tell me what this is in mathematical terms?

Comment: I'm essentially looking for a function that takes something like SurdMod[$17+21\sqrt{3}+18\sqrt{5}+7\sqrt{15}$,$13$] and returns $4+8\sqrt{3}+5\sqrt{5}+7\sqrt{15}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
surdMod[expr_, n_]:=expr /. {x_Integer y_Power -> Mod[x, n] y, x_Power :> x, 
x_Integer :> Mod[x, n]}
```

Testing:

```
surdMod[7 + 5 Sqrt[2] + 6 Sqrt[3] + 7 Sqrt[6], 4]
```

> 3 + Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[3] + 3 Sqrt[6]

```
surdMod[17 + 21 Sqrt[3] + 18 Sqrt[5] + 7 Sqrt[15], 13]
```

> 4 + 8 Sqrt[3] + 5 Sqrt[5] + 7 Sqrt[15]

```
surdMod[Sqrt[14], 3]
```

> Sqrt[14]

Comment: I'm not sure why, but your function sometimes takes the modulus of the surds.  For instance, I had a function with $\sqrt{14}$, and it returned a $\sqrt{3}$ instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. Repaired, tested, should be working.